# make virtualenv use python3

Tags: python, virtualenv

I have a virtualenv called "my_repo", when I workon this virtualenv, I get this error:

```
The path python3 (from --python=python3) does not exist
```

How can I make this env use python3?

Im on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be the path to the executable on your system.

```
mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python3 myenvname
```

That is the default path on many Linux distros, depending on your system, it may be elsewhere. If you use Linux or similar, use `which python3` to find the path to the executable.

Comment: I get this: ERROR: virtualenv "my_repo" already exists, apologies Im new to virtualenv

Comment: With `rmvirtualenv my_env_name` you can delete existing virtual envs.

Comment: right! okay let me try it

Comment: stupid question but do I have to actually install python3 first separately before this works? Because I have python2.7 installed on my machine so installing python3 would create issues no?

Comment: Yes, for virtualenv to work, you need the python version to be installed.  Depending on your OS, it could cause problems or not. Most more recent distros have both, python2.7 and python3.5 or so. Then, the `python` command will continue to point to python 2.7, but the `python3` command would point to python 3.5, so they can be installed side-by-side.

Comment: right! okay that makes a lot more sense now, i thought you only keep one python version globally and install another python version in a virtualenv

Comment: let me try that and get back to you

Comment: @C14L As long as `python3` is on your `$PATH`, which it usually is, you don't need to specify the full path when creating the virtualenv – `--python python3` is enough.